# Hard combinatorics question

Tags: combinatorics

The origin of the coordinates is a pixel. After 1 second, it splits into two particles, one
shifts to the left and the other to the right. This process is repeated every second, and the two particles at the same point are mutually destroyed (so that, for example,
two seconds later, two particles remain.) How many particles will there be in $n$ seconds?
I calculated first values using programm ($1,$
$2,$ $2,$ $4,$ $2,$ $4,$ $4,$ $8,$ $2,$ $4,$ $4,$ $8,$ $4,$ $8,$ $8,$ $16,$ $2,$ $4,$ $4,$ $8,$ $4,$ $8,$ $8,$ $16,$ $4,
$ $8,$ $8,$ $16,$ $8,$ $16,$ $16,$ $32,$ $2,$ $4,$ $4,$ $8,$ $4,$ $8,$ $8,$ $16,$ $4,$ $8,$ $8,$ $16,$ $8,$ $16,$ $16,$
$32,$ $4,$ $8,$ $8,$ $16,$ $8,$ $16,$ $16,$ $32,$ $8,$ $16,$ $16,$ $32,$ $16,$ $32,$ $32,$ $64,$ $2,$ $4,$ $4,$ $8,$ $4,
$ $8,$ $8,$ $16,$ $4,$ $8,$ $8,$ $16,$ $8,$ $16,$ $16,$ $32,$) but I still cant find any formula.

Answer (score 2):

This is called Gould's sequence, or Dress' sequence, or Glaisher's sequence; it appears in the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A001316).  The $n$-th term is the number of odd entries entries in row $n$ of Pascal's triangle.  The specific operation in OP is [Rule 90](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Rule90.html) for cellular automata, and we are counting how many $1$'s there are in every stage.  Much more is available in the OEIS link above.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I tried to find this sequence using oeis, but it didnt found something.